# how to blur text onblur event in an input

Tags: javascript, html

i have a code in which i want the text in a text field to blur a little bit when the user loses focus from the respective field

i have a code but i dont know what to change in it , since i am a beginner in javascript 
my html code -

```
Name <input type="text" id="naam" onblur="myFunction()">
```

and my js -

```
function myFunction()
{
var x=document.getElementById("fname");
x.value=x.value./*something to make it blur*/();
}
```

Comment: with blur you mean you want a little hazy like effect...blur in javascript means something else..i hope you know it..

Comment: just change the css when onblur and onfocus events are fired using their corresponding handlers. You can check my answer.

Answer (score 3):

[**Fun with blurred text**](http://css-tricks.com/fun-with-blurred-text/)

```
.blurry-text {
   color: transparent;
   text-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}
```

Using the above css, you can make a **`blur`** text effect.  Then add the class like this

```
var x=document.getElementById("fname");
x.className += ' blurry-text';
```

Hope you understood.

**Updates:**

Based on your comments, 
If you use **`jQuery`**, then simply you can add/remove class using **`addClass('blurry-text')`** / **`removeClass('blurry-text')`**.

However in pure javascript, you have to do like this

```
function blurIt() {
    var x = document.getElementById("naam");
    x.className += ' blurry-text';
}

function focusIt() {
    var x = document.getElementById("naam");
    x.className = x.className.replace("blurry-text", "");
}
```

### [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vx75r/3/)

Comment: this works, now i have another problem, i want that when the user comes back to the field, the text becomes normal

Comment: @user2906766 You can remove the class when you do `onfocus` event.  I have updated my answer, check it

Answer (score 3):

This simplest way to achieve onblur event is to use

```
document.FormName.fname.blur();
```

Try this.

Answer (score 1):

The onblur event occurs when the element, in this case the input, loses focus. You could achieve this with css only.

```
#naam{
   // Style this as you want it on blur
}

#naam:focus{
    // Style this as you want it when focused
}
```